# parsing values from property file in golang

Tags: go

For Java there is the Properties class that offers functionality to parse / interact with property file.

Is there something similar in golang standard library ?

If not, what other alternatives do I have ?

Comment: Have you done any research? Googling _"golang properties file"_, 2nd hit: [`github.com/rickar/props`](https://github.com/rickar/props): Go (golang) library for Java-style property files

Answer (score 16):

Adding on top of @Madhu's answer, you can create a very simple package to read a properties file using Scanner, and read line by line of your file skipping invalid lines (those not having the '=' char):

Example:

```
package fileutil

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "log"
)

type AppConfigProperties map[string]string

func ReadPropertiesFile(filename string) (AppConfigProperties, error) {
    config := AppConfigProperties{}

    if len(filename) == 0 {
        return config, nil
    }
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        if equal := strings.Index(line, "="); equal >= 0 {
            if key := strings.TrimSpace(line[:equal]); len(key) > 0 {
                value := ""
                if len(line) > equal {
                    value = strings.TrimSpace(line[equal+1:])
                }
                config[key] = value
            }
        }
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return config, nil
}
```

Sample test sample_test.properties :

```
host=localhost
proxyHost=test
protocol=https://
chunk=
```

Properties test:

```
package fileutil

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestReadPropertiesFile(t *testing.T) {
    props, err := ReadPropertiesFile("sample_test.properties")
    if err != nil {
        t.Error("Error while reading properties file")
    }

    if props["host"] != "localhost" || props["proxyHost"] != "test" || props["protocol"] != "https://" || props["chunk"] != "" {
        t.Error("Error properties not loaded correctly")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped me out

Answer (score 8):

**You can use this following code Instead of using 3rd Party libs**

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type Config map[string]string

func ReadConfig(filename string) (Config, error) {
    // init with some bogus data
    config := Config{
        "port":     "8888",
        "password": "abc123",
        "ip":       "127.0.0.1",
    }
    if len(filename) == 0 {
        return config, nil
    }
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    reader := bufio.NewReader(file)

    for {
        line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')

        // check if the line has = sign
        // and process the line. Ignore the rest.
        if equal := strings.Index(line, "="); equal >= 0 {
            if key := strings.TrimSpace(line[:equal]); len(key) > 0 {
                value := ""
                if len(line) > equal {
                    value = strings.TrimSpace(line[equal+1:])
                }
                // assign the config map
                config[key] = value
            }
        }
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
    return config, nil
}

func main() {
    // for this tutorial, we will hard code it to config.txt
    config, err := ReadConfig(`C:\Users\mseelam.ORADEV\GoglandProjects\MyFirstProj\data\config`)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    //fmt.Println("Config data dump :", config)

    // assign values from config file to variables
    ip := config["ip"]
    pass := config["pass"]
    port := config["port"]

    fmt.Println("IP :", ip)
    fmt.Println("Port :", port)
    fmt.Println("Password :", pass)
}
```

Comment: shouldn't this line : if len(line) > equal  be: if len(line) > equal + 1 ?

Comment: nice program dude, i hope people don't forget to add the EOF clause at the end and end up with an infinite loop

Answer (score 6):

From your question, it's not clear whether you want to parse some existing properties file(s) or you're merely interested in general approaches to have your Go program consume configuration presented in some textual form.

If you want the former, then `@icza` pointed you to the right direction: there exists at least one 3rd-party Go package which implements parsing of the Java properties files.

If you want the latter, there are *lots* of solutions to pick from:

- The standard library has packages to parse XML and JSON-formatted data streams.
- There exists a host of 3rd-party libraries to read INI-style files.
  A library exists which allows reading "hierarchical" INI files—with nested sections (Git configuration style).
- There exist 3rd-party libraries which parse custom textual formats such as YAML and TOML.
- Finally, there exist "integrated" solutions which provide for pulling bits of configuration from different sources simultaneously: the environment, the configuration files and the command-line options; https://github.com/spf13/viper is a good example of them.

TL;DR

- The standard library makes it possible to interpret XML and JSON.
- 3rd-party solutions make it possible to do everything at all.

Think through your goals, do your research, take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

If your properties file uses [TOML](https://npf.io/2014/08/intro-to-toml/) then you can use the TOML parser from 
https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml.
Here is an example I did that parses a "properties file" for me
**Properties file content(properties.ini)**

```
dbpassword="password"
database="localhost"
dbuser="user"
```

Code that is parsing the properties file

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/BurntSushi/toml"
)

// Config ...
type Config struct {
    Dbpassword string
    Database   string
    DbUser     string
}

// Reads info from config file
func ReadConfig() Config {
    var configfile = "properties.ini"
    _, err := os.Stat(configfile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Config file is missing: ", configfile)
    }

    var config Config
    if _, err := toml.DecodeFile(configfile, &config); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    //log.Print(config.Index)
    return config
}

func main() {
    config := ReadConfig()
    fmt.Printf("%s: %s: %s\n", config.Dbpassword, config.Database, config.DbUser)

}
```

Output:

```
password: localhost: user
```

Answer (score 2):

[Viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) is not a standard golang library. Actually golang does not provide much library. Here most libraries are open source on github and you have to find the best one according to your purpose.

Viper is really stable, easy to configure with few line of codes. Follow the steps to configure

> Create a config file with .toml ext. Here default.toml

```
[site.location]
country = "USA"
```

> Now create a config loader file, loader.go

```
package config

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

var c *Config

type Config struct {
    Site struct {
        Location struct {
            Country string
        }
    }
}

func init() {
    viper.SetConfigName("default")                                                   // You can any name with .toml extention, here use "default" instead of "default.toml"
    viper.AddConfigPath(os.Getenv("GOPATH") + "/src/github.com/mahfuj/The-G/config") // The folder containing default.toml
    //viper.AddConfigPath(os.Getenv("CONFIG_PATH"))
    err := viper.ReadInConfig()

    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Fatal error config file: %s", err))
    }

    c = new(Config)
    viper.Unmarshal(c)
}

func GetConfig() *Config {
    return c
}
```

> Now from application access the property

```
var x string = config.GetConfig().Site.Location.Country
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution can be used to manage properties file in Golang.
Details are here:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/magiconair/properties
https://github.com/magiconair/properties

### Sample Code

```golang
import (
    "flag"
    "github.com/magiconair/properties"
)

func main() {
    // init from a file
    p := properties.MustLoadFile("${HOME}/config.properties", properties.UTF8)

    // or multiple files
    p = properties.MustLoadFiles([]string{
            "${HOME}/config.properties",
            "${HOME}/config-${USER}.properties",
        }, properties.UTF8, true)

    // or from a map
    p = properties.LoadMap(map[string]string{"key": "value", "abc": "def"})

    // or from a string
    p = properties.MustLoadString("key=value\nabc=def")

    // or from a URL
    p = properties.MustLoadURL("http://host/path")

    // or from multiple URLs
    p = properties.MustLoadURL([]string{
            "http://host/config",
            "http://host/config-${USER}",
        }, true)

    // or from flags
    p.MustFlag(flag.CommandLine)

    // get values through getters
    host := p.MustGetString("host")
    port := p.GetInt("port", 8080)

    // or through Decode
    type Config struct {
        Host    string        `properties:"host"`
        Port    int           `properties:"port,default=9000"`
        Accept  []string      `properties:"accept,default=image/png;image;gif"`
        Timeout time.Duration `properties:"timeout,default=5s"`
    }
    var cfg Config
    if err := p.Decode(&cfg); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```